# javascript increment date by month wise from given date

Tags: javascript, date, increment

i am trying to make program . in which i have a text box with value of 2013-08-27 i want to increase this date by month wise up to 30 months

```
ex:-
2013-08-27
2013-09-27 
2013-10-27
2013-11-27
2013-12-27
2014-01-27
2014-02-27

.........
2015-01-27
```

i already googled this topic ... but i am not getting any clue how to do it.. as for i get to this code

```
var myDate = new Date();

//add a day to the date
myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate() + 1);
```

but this is giving me reslut as 11,17 i want to increase year also by month wise up to 30 months from given date please give me any clue ... sorry for bad English

Comment: use `myDate.setMonth(myDate.getMonth() + 1);`

Answer (score 3):

**Try this:**

```
var myDate = new Date();

for(var i =0;i<30; i++)
{
   myDate.setMonth(myDate.getMonth() + 1);
   console.log(myDate);

}
```

Comment: You solution does not handle month nor years

Comment: @Scription the current time in my city is `Mon Dec 02 2013 13:55:39 GMT+0400 `, the solution proposed by Mr.G gives me `Thu Jan 02 2014 13:55:39 GMT+0400`. What's wrong with his code?

Comment: According to the example at the top of the page.
When changing month, the year should also change as well.
According to your solution only the month changes.

Comment: this code is working fine.. years are also changing after 12 months interval thanks for help but i am trying to get date in yyyy-mm-dd format but its giving me date Mon Dec 02 2013 13:55:39 GMT+0400 in this format how can i change date format .. thanks for answer

Comment: @Scription - The `Date` object allows for overflow.  Months are 0-11, so if you set month to 12, it puts you on Jan of the following year.  If you set months to -1, it puts you in December of the prior year.  So this solution is generally valid.  HOWEVER - if `myDate` is on the 31st day of a month, then incrementing to a month with 30 days will *skip* that month.  (***ouch!***)